# How to show the mail sender profile image and title in inbox mail using php mail()?

Tags: php, html-email

I have a problem when sending an email with PHP
The problem is my email title and from variable is blank

**Screenshot of my email:**

[image]

I use my work email address to send an email.
My script is like this

```
public static function header($from, $cc = false, $replyTO = null) {
    $headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
    if ($replyTO) {
    $headers .= "Reply-to: ". $replyTO ."\r\n"; }
    if ($cc) {
    $headers .= "CC: ". $cc ."\r\n"; }
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

    return $headers;
}

public static function top() {
    return file_get_contents('email/top.php');
}

public static function footer() {
    return file_get_contents('email/bottom.php');;
}

public static function output( $url ) {

    $message = self::top();
    $message .= $url;
    $message .= self::footer();

    return $message;
}

public static function send($from, $to, $subject, $content) {
    if ( mail($to, $subject, $content, self::header($from)) ) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Any solution ? thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For From name:

Try the following:

```
public static function header($from,$sender_name='', $cc = false, $replyTO = null) {
    $headers = "From: ".$sender_name."<" . $from . "> \r\n";
    if ($replyTO) {
    $headers .= "Reply-to: ". $replyTO ."\r\n"; }
    if ($cc) {
    $headers .= "CC: ". $cc ."\r\n"; }
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

    return $headers;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It workings. And now, how to show my logo ?

Comment: @KadekPradnyana Welcome :-). I dont know. But that email id we stored in our contact with image means. Then it will be displayed. If I get answer and let you know..

Answer (score 1):

for the name example

```
$headers .= 'From: Steven Koelsche <info@koeltech.net>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$fullname.' <'.$emailaddress.'>' . "\r\n";
```

i assume image is tied with google+ account, your can registered your current email with them then just add your images and vala